# calculating approximate solutions to DEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I frequently come across equations of the form:
$$dy=\sin(d\theta)+...$$
where $y$ is a function of $\theta$. My lecturers normally bypass this by making the assumption that $\sin(d\theta)=d\theta$ and $\cos(d\theta)=1$. Whilst I agree that this is close, exactly how close are these solutions? I am looking for examples of it being solved exactly to see how big the errors are.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo sorry

Comment: The smaller the angles are, the closer the solution will be. At $\theta=8.1$ degrees, $\cos(\theta) = 0.99$,  so by keeping under 8 degrees, the approximation will be out by less than 1% at greatest extent.